# Over land didn't seem much easier

Tags: grammar

From the book 100 year-old man who climbed out the window and disappeared 
" over land didn't seem much easier" :

The above sentence seems wrong to me .
As I learned, over land doesn't look like a  noun and should not be placed for the subject position .
Or is the sentence reversed? 
Or is it just typical English expression? 
Would you explain the usage of the words to me?
Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: where are the (opening) closing quotes - have they gone on holiday?

Comment: Oops . Back from the holiday ~~

Comment: "doesn't look noun and should not be placed for the subject position". It seems like you have far worse grammar than the sentence you quote.

Comment: What is the context of the sentence? If there was a previous sentence describing a sea voyage, this sentence is simply eliding that part because it's understood. "over land" is short for "traveling over land".

Comment: The passage does follow a reference to a sea voyage, so as @Barmar said above.  Here's the full quote: "Over land didn’t seem much easier. Northward into Siberia where it really was cold was no solution. Nor was going westward into China."   From Jonas Jonasson, _The Hundred-Year-Old Man Who Climbed Out of the Window and Disappeared_.  (google is your friend.)

Comment: Notice that all of those sentences have elisions.

Answer (score 1):

Going "over land" versus going "by sea" also has its perils. "Going" or any other term that would convert this into a conventional sentence isn't there. "over land" is a preposition with an object that functions as a subject phrase in this informal, fast-moving account. "Over land" is contrasted with traveling by sea.

What remained was Southward . . .

Over all it seems to me to be a reasonable sentence in the style of the writer.

Comment: Confused at the first time but now I got it . Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

CalifJim at [English Forums](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CanPrepositionalPhraseServeSubject/vxjgd/post.htm) has valuable advice on the issue of 'may prepositional phrases be used as subjects [/objects] in sentences?'

> f*or you to meet the king [would be impossible]*
>
> [uses] a for ... to ... clause. for is considered a complementizer in
>   that context (according to some analytical methods), not a
>   preposition.
>
> But you can make a prepositional phrase a 'sort of' subject by pulling
>   it to the beginning. The resulting sentences are 'pretty lame',
>   however, and not all grammarians will likely agree that these phrases
>   are true subjects, since the sentences can be analyzed as something
>   like cleft transformations of an underlying sentence with a different
>   'true' subject.
>
> *In the office is where you'll find him. [You'll find him in the
>   office.]*
>
> *Before the war was when they met. [They met before the war.]*
>
> *With great care was how they proceeded. [They proceeded with great
>   care.]*

So 'Over land didn't seem much easier.' shouldn't cause many knee-jerk reactions in conversational style, but in formal writing one might like to add 'Going / Journeying'. In this example, even the 'straightened' form might be considered to benefit from the addition of the *ing*-form: *It didn't seem much easier going over land.*

Comment: Your detailed information seemed much helpful :) thanks million ~